# Saving a Python3 script and running it in IDLE

Tags: raspbian

I am working on a project and have two Pi's for a Client-Server setup. Unfortunately I don't have the physical Pi's with me right now, and won't be possible to do so for a while. So I decided to use VirtualBox to simulate two Raspbian Os and work on them as I would on the actual Pi's.

On the Virtual Machine I can write the code and run it using the terminal and the sudo nano command. I wanted to do the similar thing on the GUI, i.e writing and running the python script in the editor and IDLE. But when I save the code on the editor, I get the I/O error  as follows.

As far as I understand it, there is definitely an issue getting the root/admin privilege in the GUI mode to do what I want. Additionally, it could be that the fact that I am using the Virtual Box is causing some problems and me not being an expert in either yet is tripping me up.

Basically I am hoping for some way to give me root privileges to run the code in GUI.

[image]